# Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, email, frontend, email-templates

> Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/email_items.phtml on line 10

```
<?php $items = $block->getItemDetails() ?>
 <table>
  <thead>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Condition</strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($items as $key => $itemName): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?= $itemName ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your variable $items isn't an array.
What does the method getItemDetails return? What kind of class is $block?